# Why doesn't this bubbleSort method work? Why does it need another for loop?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am having a problem with bubbleSort() in java. What doesn't this sort the array

```
import java.util.*;

public class Example {
    public static void bubbleSort(int[] x){
        for(int i=0; i<x.length-1; i++){
            if(x[i]>x[i+1]){
                int t=x[i];
                x[i]=x[i+1];
                x[i+1]=t;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] xr={99,78,67,12,65,54,43,23,67,11};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(xr)); //99,78,67
        bubbleSort(xr);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(xr)); //11, 12, 23, 43, 
    }
}
```

This is the output of the given code:

[99, 78, 67, 12, 65, 54, 43, 23, 67, 11]
[78, 67, 12, 65, 54, 43, 23, 67, 11, 99]

Comment: because you only sort for one element, you need to sort for them all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing only once. You would have to do this a couple more times:

```
public static void bubbleSort(int[] x){
    for(int i=x.length - 1; i>0; i--){
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
            if(x[j]>x[j+1]){
                int t=x[j];
                x[j]=x[j+1];
                x[j+1]=t;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It checks only adjacent values, so when minimal is the last one, after one run it will be on the second last position (only one check and position swapping). So you need to do this as many times as there is elements in the array, but not always for the whole set (after the first run the maximal element will be on the last position and so on).

Comment: I didn't understand the code sir. I would be great if you could explain the code for me, if you don't mind. Doesn't the for loop check all the elements and compare them and sort them from the first for loop?

Comment: @ThisuraThenuka added some explanation, hope it's more clear;)

Answer (score 0):

Read the bubble sort again.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/bubble_sort_algorithm.htm

`for(int i=0; i<x.length-1; i++)`

Your loop will go through the array only one time.

````
                int t=x[j];
                x[j]=x[j+1];
                x[j+1]=t;
            }```
Within the loop, you are just swapping sibilling two elements as lower first if first one higher than the next one.

This will just bring the highest value to end of the array. Then what about the next highest value?. To sort completely, you need to do this swapping array element count number of times. O(n2)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

so it should be like,

public static void bubbleSort(int[] x){
 for(int j=0; j<x.length-1; j++){
         for(int i=0; i<x.length-1; i++){
             if(x[i]>x[i+1]){
                 int t=x[i];
                 x[i]=x[i+1];
                 x[i+1]=t;
             }
         }
     }
 }
````